# Finding centroids of cluster index in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, cluster-analysis

I have an MxN matrix of binary values corresponding to pixels in an image. E.g:

```
> mat<- matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), nrow = 5, byrow = T)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    1    1    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    0    0    0
[5,]    1    1    0    0    0
```

The matrix is populated from a java script that determines if a pixel falls within a given criteria (e.g. if a pixel is "greenspace" or not). Values of 1 are true, 0 false.

I convert the values of 1 in the matrix to the corresponding row index:

```
mat2[mat == 1]<- row(mat)[mat == 1]
mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    2    2    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    4    4    0    0    0
[5,]    5    5    0    0    0
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to find the centroid of the row indices in each cluster of non-zero values. I.e. there are two clusters of non-zero values there, with centroids of 1.5 and 2.5 (means of 1,1,2,2 and 4,4,5,5 respectively).

I'm at a loss on how to perform this. I've attempted k-means clustering, but it does not seem correct for this operation (mind you, this is not my expertise at all so the probability I was doing it incorrectly is high). What is the best way in R to calculate the centroids in this manner?

Apologies for my naivety - this is not my field, and my work really starts after I have the results from this analysis.

Comment: What defines a "cluster"? Is this some sort of adjacency matrix? It would be helpful to define what the rows, columns, and values represent. Right now this doesn't sound like a clearly specified problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've edited my original question for clarification

Comment: A "cluster" is still not well defined. If row three wasn't there, would it still be a cluster? Does there have to be am empty row in between clusters? What if cells 4,5 and 5,5 also had non-zero values. Would that form another cluster?